# QT How to embed an application into QT widget which is a background-transparent widget that runs behind the main QT widget?

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, win32-process

There is a 2 overlapping widgets (A and B widgets) and they are fully screen in the designer. I want to embed an application to the widget A which has a widget stack order lower than the widget B. So, I want to run the exe in A widget as a background transparent widget of the B widget. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: You can't. See [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) to learn about the implications of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: hi @IInspectable, what I really need is to embed application (.exe) to a widget (its done) then make the same widget transparent with the .exe inside.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can try to look into `QWinHost`. It can take the process ID of the exe, and embed its window into its own widget.